# How do I Pass Html form image arrays to the Google App Engine(Python)?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, forms, http-post

I'm using the Python implementation of the Google App Engine. When I try to pass an array of image input tags from an html form, I can't seem to pick it up in the Python controller.

**The Html:**

```
<form action="/addImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="images" />
  <input type="file" name="images" />
  <input type="file" name="images" />
</form>
```

**The Python:**

```
class AddImages(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    images = self.request.get_all('images')

    for img in images:
        if img != None:
            img_entity.blob = db.Blob(img)

    self.response.out.write("Upload Succeeded")
```

When I try this, I get the dreaded unicode/str error:

```
TypeError: Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode
```

at the line where:

```
db.Blob(img)
```

I followed most of the tutorials, but none of them seemed to discuss this particular issue.

Comment: did you try `img.encode()` in `db.Blob()`?

Comment: I could encode unicode into utf-8 or ascii, but wouldn't that drop some of the file data?

Comment: You are aware you're going to run into requests that are too large if you try to upload more than 10MB of data across ALL the fields, right?

I'd recommend using the BlobStore. It makes a lot of this headache go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

attribute on your form tag, see i.e. http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg03314.html. Googling for your error turns up several other instances of the problem.

If you still have problems once you've added the `enctype`, just try `db.Blob(str(img))` and / or `db.Blob(img.encode('utf-8'))` as also suggested by threads like the above. You can also try `images =self.request.str_GET['images']` or something similar.

Comment: agf, if you read my original code, you'll see that enctype was included. str(img) worked perfectly though. Thanks!